# Different Zener Diode Symbols

Tags: diodes, zener, symbol

In the past I have seen two different symbols for a zener diode. One shows the complete "Z" shape on the cathode, and one shows more of an "L" shape on the cathode (see images below):

[image]

What is the difference between these? Do they actually have different meanings, or are they two ways of showing the same thing? Perhaps one is European and one is American? I always thought that they were simply two ways of showing the same thing, but a coworker of mine questioned it and now I am looking for confirmation.

Comment: wikipedia has yet a different symbol, a sort of slopey Z. The lower 'Z' symbol has a danger of being confused with a Schottky diode symbol, which the top 'L' one cannot.

Comment: Why just pick on the poor zener - there are lots of components with multiple symbols - they tend to be legacy items from different times and places or even particular 'house' styles.

Comment: I have never seen the upper one until now. The cathode mark on the Zener symbol should have a 'Z' appearance and the mark on the Schottky symbol should have an 'S' appearance. According to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The base symbol I can fine no definite standard reference for.  I'd guess the majority of us would use it.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fIyaqTm.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Graphical samples for the **Australian Standard AS 1102 (1989) Graphical symbols for electrotechnical** does appear to reference this symbol.  I don't have a copy, so I cannot confirm this.

**Europe:** International Electrotechnical Commission **IEC60617 (2012) Graphical Symbols for Diagrams** provide the following:

[image: Zener Diode - IEC60617]

with the IEC60617 (1996) version defining the bars.
[image: Diode Bars]
for:

- Schottky
- Tunnel
- Zener
- Bi-directional
- Unitunnel

Their usage of straight bars (05-02-04) is for Bi-directional or breakdown diode.

[image: Bi-directional or breakdown diode]

**US:** **IEEE 315 (1975) Standard for Graphic Symbols for Electrical and Electronics Diagrams** provides the straight bar symbol:

[image: Zener - IEEE 315]

**ANSI Y32.2 (1975) Graphic Symbols for Electrical and Electronics Diagrams** has been superseded by IEEE315.  It references the same symbol as IEEE315.

Comment: Hmm, thought I'd accepted this answer a long time ago. Your chart showing the different symbols with the different descriptions was very helpful. I am accepting that the first symbol in my question is for a unidirectional zener diode and the second symbol is for a bidirectional zener, such as a bidirectional TVS diode.

Answer (score 0):

There are no differences in meaning of two symbols you showed. 
Here is another of Zener diode symbol:
[image: Zener diode]

Most of electronic engineers would recognize all of them in a correct way (I mean - as Zener Diode).
 Additionally there will be some reference (Voltage/part name/number) to make schematic clear.

Comment: I am aware of and familiar with the different symbols, and like I said I generally treat them the same, but I am trying to determine if there is a reason certain symbols are used instead of others