# Is there any meaning attached to the Zener diode symbol?

Tags: circuit-analysis, circuit-design

Is there any meaning to the Zener diode symbol?

The triangle is similar to a normal diode which originally indicated current flowing in one direction only.

Is there any hidden meaning to the yellow part?

[image]

Comment: Rotate that bit ANTIclockwise by 90 degrees. See what it looks like now? Spoiler: It's a "Z"

Comment: @enhzflep oh, interesting! I have never noticed that.

Comment: In the orientation it's shown in now, also, it's the same sort of shape as a Zener diode's I-V curve.

Comment: I think it is just a variation of the "regular" diode symbol which was added without any second thought. All the "hidden" meanings here are probably just speculations.

Answer (score 3):

I've always understood the symbol to be a stylised 'Z' for Zener.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fnkG1t.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. The 'Z' is more recognisable when the symbol is rotated.*

[image]

*Figure 2. A Zener diode in the house style of [Elektor](https://elektor.com) magazine from the 1970s. Here the 'Z' is more clearly visible than with the classic symbol.*

Comment: Seeing the variety of symbols in this answer (https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/281051/different-zener-diode-symbols) it makes a lot of sense that we prefer the "Z like" for Zener and the "S like" for Schottky.